# filter after flatMap spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple example

```
val arrayStructureData = Seq(
    Row("test1|value1"),
    Row("test2|value2"),
    Row("test3|value3")
  )

val arrayStructureSchema = new StructType()
    .add("name", StringType)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arrayStructureData), arrayStructureSchema)

import spark.implicits._

val distPhens = df.flatMap(row => row.getString(0).split("\\|"))
    .filter(x => x.like("test[0-9]+"))
    .toDF("distinct_phens")
```

where I'm trying to run `filter` after running `flatMap`. The desired output is :

```
value1
value2
value3
```

If I understand correctly, `like` expects a column but I am not sure how to "refer" to the column after `flatMap` has been executed.

I need this `filter` operation to run after `flatMap`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the column object using `col`, and do an `rlike` filter:

```
val result = df.flatMap(row => row.getString(0).split("\\|")).filter(col("value").rlike("test[0-9]+"))

result.show
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|test1|
|test2|
|test3|
+-----+
```